# Execute Shell command in android app

Tags: java, android, shell

I have an android app for rooted phone in which i am trying to disable an application using shell command.

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'pm disable com.bt.bms'");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    int numRead;
    char[] buffer = new char[5000];
    StringBuffer commandOutput = new StringBuffer();
    while ((numRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        commandOutput.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    process.waitFor();
    XposedBridge.log(commandOutput.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Whenever i execute it i see a toast notification "System UI has been granted permissions: *pm disable com.bt.bms*  "
But the app is not getting disabled.
Whereas when i run the same command in Terminal, it works fine.

Comment: Does the same command work if you execute it manually in an adb root shell?

Comment: yes it works through the adb root shell